# Is there an NPM package for QuestDB?

Tags: node.js, npm, questdb

I’m new to QuestDB, and I‘m wondering if there’s an npm package for it.
I can see an [npmjs.com/questdb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/questdb) package, but it doesn’t seem to have any data in it. Please tell me if there is.
Thanks!

Comment: It seems not. In the official documentation, I haven't found anything about it. But You can verify this.  https://questdb.io/docs/introduction/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an empty placeholder package added by one of QuestDB team members.

As of now QuestDB does not have dedicated JS client (as in fact no dedicated clients in any other programming language). It relies mostly on compatibility with Postgres Driver as well as well as platform specific REST clients with CSV, JSON serialisations.

QuestDB also accepts messages in Influx Line Protocol serialisation format but unlike InfluxDB itself instead of HTTP it uses TCP transport. It makes sense to add NodeJS client with ILP serialisation and TCP transport and that will be QuestDB JS client then.

Comment: Just came here to say there is now a nodejs library for data ingestion, using the ILP protocol, and also that QuestDB now supports both TCP and HTTP for ILP ingestion, which means you could use an influx client to ingest data into questdb. https://github.com/questdb/nodejs-questdb-client